# Microsoft Graph API - Excel: Modify table range

Tags: excel, graph, range

I have a worksheet with some pre-existing data on it.

I created a table using:

```
/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{id}/workbook/worksheets/{sheetId}/tables/add
```

with the request body as an example:

```
{ "address": "C3:K243" }
```

Everything works fine - I can see table created correctly.

Now based on my internal business logic I need to modify table address. I need to add or remove some already existing rows with data from my table range. In other words based on some condition I need either expand or shrink my table range without touching data.

I cannot find a way to do that using MS Graph API.

Windows Desktop version of Excel has a specific method `ListObject.Resize(range)` but I cannot find similar method in MS Graph API.